# Guardar valores de un input, para calcular un puntaje total

Tags: html, html5

Lo que sucede, es que estoy haciendo un cuestionario en HTML5, y necesito calcular el puntaje total del participante cuando presione un botón, las opciones de respuestas estan en inputs, y tienen un valor de 1 las correctas, y que al darle al botón sume el total de las opciones seleccionadas

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Arte</legend>
    <p>¿En que museo está la Mona Lisa?  <input type="radio" name="HAP01" value="0"> Galería Uffizi  <input type="radio" name="HAP01" value="1">Louvre  <input type="radio" name="HAP01" value="0">British Museum</p>
    <p>¿En qué año nacio Vicent van Gogh?  <input type="radio" name="HAP02" value="1">1853  <input type="radio" name="HAP02" value="0">1820  <input type="radio" name="HAP02" value="0">1876</p>
    <p>"La piedad" es una escultura de  <input type="radio" name="HAP03" value="0">Bernini  <input type="radio" name="HAP03" value="0">Da Vinci  <input type="radio" name="HAP03" value="1">Miguel Ángel</p>
    <p>¿Quién pintó "El Jardin de las delicias"?  <input type="radio" name="HAP04" value="1">El Bosco  <input type="radio" name="HAP04" value="0">Francisco Goya  <input type="radio" name="HAP04" value="0">El Greco</p>
    <p>¿Cuándo nació Francisco Goya?  <input type="radio" name="HAP05" value="0">1796  <input type="radio" name="HAP05" value="1">1746  <input type="radio" name="HAP05" value="0">1806</p>
    <p>¿Cuál es el estilo de Notre Dame?  <input type="radio" name="HAP06" value="1">Arquitectura Gótica  <input type="radio" name="HAP06" value="0">Arquitectura Barroca  <input type="radio" name="HAP06" value="0">Arquitectura Romántica</p>
    <p>¿Cuál es la galería de arte más grande en el mundo?  <input type="radio" name="HAP07" value="1">Gagosian Gallery, USA<input type="radio" name="HAP07" value="0">The Saatchi Galley, Inglaterra<input type="radio" name="HAP07" value="0">Marlborough fine art, España</p>
</fieldset>
```

Esa es una pregunta, y sus opciones de respuesta, cuando le de al boton sume el valor de la opción para despues mostrarlo, puede ser en JS o cualquier otro

Comment: Deberias agregar mas HTML.

Comment: @alanfcm Eso eso es lo más relevante de todo el codigo, solo preguntas y respuestas de ese tipo

Comment: Necesitas utilizar JavaScript para esto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con jQuery seleccionando los inputs que fueron chequeados y sumando su valor asi:

```js
function calcular() {
  var respuestas = $("input:checked");
  var total = 0;
  $.each(respuestas, function() {
    total += parseInt(this.value);
  });
  console.log(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Arte</legend>
    <p>¿En que museo está la Mona Lisa?  <input type="radio" name="HAP01" value="0"> Galería Uffizi  <input type="radio" name="HAP01" value="1">Louvre  <input type="radio" name="HAP01" value="0">British Museum</p>
    <p>¿En qué año nacio Vicent van Gogh?  <input type="radio" name="HAP02" value="1">1853  <input type="radio" name="HAP02" value="0">1820  <input type="radio" name="HAP02" value="0">1876</p>
    <p>"La piedad" es una escultura de  <input type="radio" name="HAP03" value="0">Bernini  <input type="radio" name="HAP03" value="0">Da Vinci  <input type="radio" name="HAP03" value="1">Miguel Ángel</p>
    <p>¿Quién pintó "El Jardin de las delicias"?  <input type="radio" name="HAP04" value="1">El Bosco  <input type="radio" name="HAP04" value="0">Francisco Goya  <input type="radio" name="HAP04" value="0">El Greco</p>
    <p>¿Cuándo nació Francisco Goya?  <input type="radio" name="HAP05" value="0">1796  <input type="radio" name="HAP05" value="1">1746  <input type="radio" name="HAP05" value="0">1806</p>
    <p>¿Cuál es el estilo de Notre Dame?  <input type="radio" name="HAP06" value="1">Arquitectura Gótica  <input type="radio" name="HAP06" value="0">Arquitectura Barroca  <input type="radio" name="HAP06" value="0">Arquitectura Romántica</p>
    <p>¿Cuál es la galería de arte más grande en el mundo?  <input type="radio" name="HAP07" value="1">Gagosian Gallery, USA<input type="radio" name="HAP07" value="0">The Saatchi Galley, Inglaterra<input type="radio" name="HAP07" value="0">Marlborough fine art, España</p>
</fieldset>

<button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
```